# Jewish table manners

Tags: halacha, eating, derech-eretz-manners

I want to know if it's proper for a Jew to spit out bones or anything he doesn't want to swallow on top of the table he sits at.

Comment: Welcome! Like Wikipedia, this site makes no guarantee of validity, and **[does not offer](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1734)** professional (particularly rabbinic) advice. Treat information you find here as if it came from a crowd of your friends. [See more on why it's important to take personal questions of Jewish practice to your Rabbi.](/q/9146)

Answer (score 5):

Indeed there is a prohibition called Bal Teshaktzu, not to be disgusting.

This is codified in the Shulchan Aruch ([YD 116:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.116.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)). In his commentary on this law, the [Kaf Hachaim](https://www.sefaria.org/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.116.76.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) speaks of your case, writing **it is forbidden to extract food from one's mouth**.

The gemara in [Chagiga 5a](https://www.sefaria.org/Chagigah.5a.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) also refers to your case

> Additionally, when Rabbi Yoḥanan reached this verse, he cried: “For
> God shall bring every work into the judgment concerning every hidden
> thing” (Ecclesiastes 12:14). [...] And similarly, Shmuel said: **This is
> referring to one who spits in the presence of another and his friend
> is disgusted by his action.**

More generally, one is forbidden to do things that others will find disgusting (see [here](https://www.torahmusings.com/2012/06/disgusting-behavior/) for more details).